# Payer "en espèces" ou "par espèces" ?

Tags: prépositions, commerce

Are both **"en espèces"** and **"par espèces"** considered correct?

According to the Larousse online dictionary,

> **En espèces**, en argent liquide (par opposition à *par chèque* ou *avec une carte de crédit*).

However, I have heard French people say "par espèces", and on a receipt it is also written this way:

[image: Règlement par Espèces]

According to Google Ngram Viewer, the version with "en" is much more common in books than the version with "par":

[image: Google Ngram "en espèces", "par espèces"]

Maybe it is becoming common to use "par" for all forms of payment, such as "par espèces", "par carte", and "par chèque"?

Comment: The capital letter makes me think it's just a form that has a “Règlement par” field, which would be proper grammar for “carte” or “chèque”, and is only a little unfortunate for “espèces”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Bescherelle, in this case :

- the preposition "**en**" : indicates a way of payement
- the preposition "**par**" : indicates a mode of payement which is a particular way of payement

That's why the dictionnary makes an opposition between cash (which is money) and check or credit/debit card which are a mode to finally pay with money.

"*Règlement par espèces*" if not on a bill (context helping to understand)  could have the meaning "regulation by species". "*espèces*" has the meaning of "species" too. Correct usage is also "payer en espèces".

We also say :

"*payer en monnaie fiduciaire*", "*payer en numéraire*", "*payer en liquide*", "*payer en tickets-restaurant*"

"*payer en monnaie de singe*"

"*payer en nature*"

"*payer en ligne*" : the preposition "*en*" indicate here a location like for "*à*" in "*payer à la livraison*" or for "*sur*" in "*payer sur place*". It precises the place where the payement takes place.

"*payer par mensualités*", "*payer par virement*"

Answer (score 6):

"Paiement par espèces" n'est pas standard. Le texte sur ce reçu pourrait avoir été écrit sans tenir compte du l'usage standard, comme le laisse également croire l'utilisation des majuscules pour les mots "Ventes" et "Espèces".