# How can I use the preposition apart correctly regarding the method of payment?

Tags: prépositions

In the following sentences (examples from Rosetta Stone):

- Ils payent **avec** des pièces.
- Elle paye **par** chèque.
- Il paye **par** carte de crédit.
- Je paye **en** espèces.

The first uses `avec`, the second and third use `par`, and the fourth uses `en`. All of them refer to the method of payment but for me it looks like it is fine to replace one with another and also I don't understand how I can use them apart correctly.

So why is the preposition different depending on each method of payment?

And how can I decide which preposition to use if I don't know it in advance?

Comment: See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/payer-en-esp%C3%A8ces-ou-par-esp%C3%A8ces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**en**" is used for **currency**: 
je paye en euros, en dolards, en bitcoins

it is also used to say that you pay with **cash** : je paye en espèces, en liquide, en cash

"**par**" will be used for a payment **method** (other than cash): je paye par chèque (check), par carte de credit (credit card), par virement (bank transfer), par paypal ...

"**avec**" is used to define the **object(s)** used to pay :
je paye avec ma carte de crédit (with my credit card), avec des bons cadeaux (with voucher)

When the word represents both a method and the object used as the credit card you can use either :
Je paye par carte de crédit / Je paye avec ma carte de crédit

Comment: *Cash* can also be used as an adverb, without a preposition: *je paie cash*.

Comment: @Greg "payer cash" veut dire "payer la totalité en une seule fois" pas le moyen de payement, du moins en France

Answer (score 0):

It's not that much related to the method of payment then related to the choice of words. Here are other ways perfectly valid, at least, from Quebec ;)

***Ils payent avec des pièces.***

- Ils payent par pièces de monnaie.
- Ils payent en monnaie.

***Elle paye par chèque.***

- Elle paye avec un chèque.
- Elle paye en chèque.

***Il paye par carte de crédit.***

- Il paye avec une carte de crédit.
- Il paye en crédit.

***Je paye en espèces.***

- Je paye avec des espèces.
- Je paye par espèces.

Probably that the one looking best in all situations is with ***avec***.